# В каких случаях QFile::copy и QDir::rename возвращает false?

Tags: c++, qt

недавно в универе задали написать файловый менеджер в стиле Total Commander. Я решил использовать для этого `Qt Creator`, так как мне он нравится. Возникла проблема переноса файлов и папок в другие директории. Большинство ситуаций решает вот этот код:

```
    void MainWindow::on_moveButton_clicked()
{
    QFileInfo fileInfo = model->fileInfo(current_index);
    if(fileInfo.isDir())
    {
        QDir dir = fileInfo.absoluteFilePath();
        QString oldPath = fileInfo.absoluteFilePath();
        if(current_panel == ui->leftPanel)
        {
            QString newPath = rightPath + '/' + fileInfo.fileName();
            if(!dir.rename(oldPath, newPath))
            {
                QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "That folder can't be moved");
            }
        }
        else if(current_panel == ui->rightPanel)
        {
            QString newPath = leftPath + '/' + fileInfo.fileName();
            if(!dir.rename(oldPath, newPath))
            {
                QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "That folder can't be moved");
            }
        }
    }
    else if (fileInfo.isFile())
    {
        QFile file(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
        bool check = true;
        if(current_panel == ui->leftPanel)
        {
            if(!file.copy(rightPath + '/' + fileInfo.fileName()))
            {
                QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "That file can't be moved");
                check = false;
            }
            if(check)
            {
                file.remove(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
            }
        }
        else if(current_panel == ui->rightPanel)
        {
            if(!file.copy(leftPath + '/' + fileInfo.fileName()))
            {
                QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "That file can't be moved");
                check = false;
            }
            if(check)
            {
                file.remove(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но всё же существуют ситуации, которые не позволяют совершить копирование файлов/папок в другие директории. Такие ситуации возникают, когда `QDir::rename` или `QFile::copy` возвращают `false`. Одними из таких ситуаций являются: перемещение папки из одного диска на другой (данный случай характерен на Windows системе); копирование `.exe` файла. Следовательно, напрашивается вопрос: в каких случаях `QDir::rename` и `QFile::copy` возвращают `false`? Знание этого поможет исправить вышеупомянутые случаи и поможет нормализовать работу функции перемещения/копирования файлов/папок в другие директории.

Comment: Все случаи не учтешь, всё остальное написано в официальной документации по Qt.

Comment: Интересно, а когда в универе будут давать задание написать что то типа Виндовз ? :) по вопросу, уйдите при работе с файлами от qt, полно библиотек посвещеннывх работы с файлами учитывающие разные подводные камни, их там очень не мало..

Comment: Немного поработав с функциями , можно смело сказать что нужно просто правильно обращаться к файлам или директориям.От сюда следует что дело в работе файловой системы той или иной операционной системы. Нужно просто разобраться именно с работой файловой системой и абстрагироваться от работы функции.